# Zend MySQL: Unknown Column in Where Clause - when using GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework, magento

In Magento I am using Zend DDL to create a query to group_concat() a tables values into a single field called 'websites'.

The query works fine until there is a where clause added.

```
SELECT
  `main_table`.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(website.website_id) AS `websites`
FROM
  `megamenu_entity` AS `main_table`
   LEFT JOIN `megamenu_website` AS `website`
   ON main_table.entity_id = website.megamenu_id
WHERE
  (websites = '1')
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`
```

which gives the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'websites' in 'where clause'

Why is this? Can anyone help me out with this? Ideally in Zend DDL. This is what im doing at the moment.

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
  array('website' => $collection->getTable('megamenu/megamenu_website')),
  "main_table.entity_id = website.megamenu_id",
  array('websites' => new Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(website.website_id)'))
)->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause will not recognize column aliases. Column aliases can be used in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

Updated your query to use the original column name, such as:

```
SELECT
  `main_table`.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(website.website_id) AS `websites`
FROM
  `megamenu_entity` AS `main_table`
   LEFT JOIN `megamenu_website` AS `website`
   ON main_table.entity_id = website.megamenu_id
WHERE
  (website.website_id = '1')
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`
```

Comment: Absolute lifesaver, i never knew that i couldn't use column aliases in where clauses. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
SELECT * FROM 
(                     
SELECT
`main_table`.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(website.website_id) AS `websites`
FROM
`megamenu_entity` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `megamenu_website` AS `website`
ON main_table.entity_id = website.megamenu_id ) E
WHERE
(E.websites = '1')
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`
```

Comment: Actually column alias name is not using as column name for that we have to write inline views.

Answer (score 0):

Try ths query..

```
SELECT
  `main_table`.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(website.website_id) AS `websites`
FROM
  `megamenu_entity` AS `main_table`
   LEFT JOIN `megamenu_website` AS `website`
   ON main_table.entity_id = website.megamenu_id
WHERE
  ((GROUP_CONCAT(website.website_id)) = '1')
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`
```

Your query not working because **where** is execute before **group**.